# Determining a recurrence relation for a given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

```
void function(int A[], int i, int j){
    if (j == i+1) 
        if (A[i] > A[j])
            swap(A,i,j)
        else {
            int k = (j-i+1)/3;
            function(A,i,j-k); 
            function(A,i+k,j);
            function(A,i,j-k); 
        }
}
```

This piece of code is taken from a past mid-term exam in my Analysis of algorithms class. It was asked of the students to derive a recurrence relation that describes the behaviour of this function. I've seen a few examples on the internet on how this process is done, but I just can't figure out how to apply it on this particular function, the i and j indexes are really confusing to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try making a sample array (10 elements or so) and calculate what the actual values of the indexes become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the `[i,j-k],[i+k,j],[i,j-k]` are `2/3` of the `[i,j]`. So you are dividing your problem to `3` parts when each part is two third of the original size. Therefore your recurrence relation is `T(n) = 3*T(n*2/3)`. You can solve this using Master theorem.